# Conversion of scalar variable in query

Tags: sql-server, date

I am working with public database Wide World Importers and I try to make some query.For input in this query I want to use scalar variables. You can see code below:

```
DECLARE @SupplierID int = 7
DECLARE @YearMonth  NVARCHAR = '2013.1'

SELECT  
    pur.SupplierID, SUM(purst.TransactionAmount) AS TotalTransaction, 
    CONCAT(YEAR(pur.OrderDate), '.', MONTH(pur.OrderDate)) AS YearMonth
FROM 
    [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrders] AS pur
INNER JOIN 
    [Purchasing].[SupplierTransactions] AS purst ON purst.SupplierID = pur.SupplierID
WHERE 
    pur.SupplierID = @SupplierID 
    AND YearMonth = @YearMonth
GROUP BY 
    pur.OrderDate, pur.SupplierID
```

Above code work well and give me good result (but without scalar variable @YearMonth). You can see result below:

[image]

But when I try to include YearMonth like scalar variable into this query I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3831
> Invalid column name 'YearMonth'

So can anybody help me how to fix this problem and make query properly?

Comment: You need to use `CONCAT(year(pur.OrderDate), '.',month(pur.OrderDate)) = @YearMonth`. With current approach system tries to look into tables columns and cannot find `YearMonth` column.

Comment: That solution isn't really recommended though, @gofr1, as the query would not be SARGable.

Comment: @Larnu Of course it is not sargable at all. I am just trying to point out what was wrong with the query in a first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a column declared in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`. You need to reference the actual columns in the table in the `WHERE`, or use a subquery or CTE.

What you should be doing here, however, is using proper date logic:

```sql
DECLARE @SupplierID int = 7,
        @StartDate date = '20130101',
        @EndDate date = '20130201';

SELECT PO.SupplierID,
       SUM(ST.TransactionAmount) AS TotalTransaction,
       CONCAT(YEAR(PO.OrderDate), '.', MONTH(PO.OrderDate)) AS YearMonth
FROM [Purchasing].[PurchaseOrders] PO
     INNER JOIN [Purchasing].[SupplierTransactions] ST ON ST.SupplierID = PO.SupplierID
WHERE PO.SupplierID = @SupplierID
  AND PO.OrderDate >= @StartDate
  AND PO.OrderDate < @EndDate
GROUP BY PO.OrderDate,
         PO.SupplierID;
```

I also change your aliases to something a bit more appropriate.

Comment: Your code work very well with scalar variable e.g @StartDate in format '20130101', but in my code I need to have scalar variable on input  in this format  '2013.1'.This variable contain only Year and Month and for that reason a convert variable into name YearMonth

Comment: Why do you "need" to, @silent_hunter? You are quering a column that contains a date and time data type, so use scalar variables that are also a date and time data type.

Comment: The value of the `@StartDate` isn't in a "format" either. The date and time data types are binary values, and have no format. The only thing in a "format" is the **literal string**, which is in an unambiguous format so the value can be implicitly cast to a `date` without issue.

Comment: @silent_hunter Is your "need" driven by your goal of using SSRS or some other report tool to run the query. If so, you forcing an GUI implementation (for your parameter selection) into the tsql code that will only lead to poor performance and (probably) more issues to be addressed at a later date.